# Console hosted WCF service does not Trace

Tags: c#, wcf, servicehost

I have written a simple service contract (`IServiceObject`) and then implemented it (`ServiceObject`).  I host it in a `ServiceHost` object that is contained within a console application.  Within one of my `OperationContract` methods I call `Trace.WriteLine(...)`.  I also call `Console.WriteLine(...)`.  Within the console application, before and after I `Open()` the `ServiceHost`, I call `Trace.WriteLine(...)` and `Console.WriteLine(...)`.

Trace is set to autoflush, and has 2 listeners (`TextWriterTraceListener` and `ConsoleTraceListener`).  When the console application fires up, all Trace and Console `WriteLine()` calls are written to their respective logs.  So the Trace call will write to my text file and to my console and the Console call will write to my console.

When my client application (a separate application) calls the `OperationContract` method, only the `Console.WriteLine(...)` calls within it are displayed on the console screen.  The `Trace.WriteLine(...)` calls are not written to the console screen or the text file.

When I query (from within the `OperationContract` method) for the Trace stats (outputting them to the console screen with `Console.WriteLine(...)`) I am told that there are 2 listeners in Trace (Text and Console) and that autoflush is on.

Does anyone know why my calls to `Trace.WriteLine(...)` would fail to write to either of the listeners only from within the `OperationContract` method?  Are there some specific attributes I need to decorate my `ServiceObject` class with?  Are there some settings I might be missing somewhere?  It seems to me that the Tracing is configured correctly since it works everywhere except from within my `OperationContract` methods...

This seems to be problem, my shared library that contains only my OperationContract and its implementation:

### IServiceObject.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SuccessEHS.Dev.Shared
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IServiceObject
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool Test(string text);
    }
}
```

### ServiceObject.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace SuccessEHS.Dev.Shared
{
    public class ServiceObject : IServiceObject
    {
        public bool Test(string text)
        {
            Console.Write("Testing 1");
            Trace.Write("..2");
            Console.Write("..3");
            Trace.Write("..4");
            Console.WriteLine("..5");

            Console.WriteLine("CW: {0}", text);
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("TW: {0}", text));

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Shared.csproj (which I suspect is the culprit but am not sure why):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{23F9A333-9CC8-43FA-8A01-06BEA8B9D0E6}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Shared</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>SharedTest</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <CodeAnalysisLogFile>bin\Debug\Shared.dll.CodeAnalysisLog.xml</CodeAnalysisLogFile>
    <CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>true</CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>
    <CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>GlobalSuppressions.cs</CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets</CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\\Rules</CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <CodeAnalysisLogFile>bin\Release\Shared.dll.CodeAnalysisLog.xml</CodeAnalysisLogFile>
    <CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>true</CodeAnalysisUseTypeNameInSuppression>
    <CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>GlobalSuppressions.cs</CodeAnalysisModuleSuppressionsFile>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\\Rule Sets</CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRuleSets>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\\Rules</CodeAnalysisRuleDirectories>
    <CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>true</CodeAnalysisIgnoreBuiltInRules>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

I built a new server console app to host a new shared library and a new client console app to connect to it and had no issues.  When I then imported this project as the shared library (above) the Tracing failed to work that was found in ServiceObject.cs.  Any new ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code sample that will reproduce the problem?  I am guessing it won't be required (as I imagine this is some sort of trace configuration issue), but it may be helpful for people reading and answering the question.

Comment: I am going to start a new project that has minimal code to see if I can get that to trace.  Once I have it written, I will post it.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) describes how to enable *and* configure trace listeners/sources for WCF.  There are multiple pieces, and if you miss some of them I expect tracing would not work.

Comment: I am not looking to enable WCF sources.  I read the article but it provided no clue to resolve this issue.  I only want to know why when I use the .net Trace class in a hosted object it doesn't produce any trace output, even though the configuration hasn't changed since the object became hosted.  And the program that hosted the object has no issues tracing, even while the object is being hosted.  Good article for setting up WCF sources though.  (Note: when I enable the WCF sources, I get all of their tracing but still not Trace.WriteLine(...) tracing)

Comment: @Schrader: Bummer man.  I'll check out your code on the OP when you get it posted.

Comment: Yeah, it is boggling my mind and I am too stubburn to give up without some kind of answer, even if the answer turns out to be a bug report to MS :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the WCF [Service Trace Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795.aspx). See if this provides you with any assistance.

Comment: I use the ServiceTraceViewer when I view data from the WCF listeners.  However, nothing from the Trace listeners is showing up there, not even the tracing that is working in the hosting application.  Though I would not imagine it to show up there as those are listeners not linked into the System.Diagnostics.Trace listeners.